# how to create urlshortner by using php

Tags: php, mysql, easyphp

I have created url shortner by using the link http://devlup.com/programming/php/create-url-shortener-php/853/  for this i am using EasyPhp5.3.6.0,,but i am not finding the required output,,that means after clicking shortened url it is not redirecting to the original page.Possibly i am thinking the issue is on database side
This is the steps which i did in database side,please let me know anything wrong

First i went to Configuration->PhpMyAdmin link ,,Then i created Database named "leaf" here i didnt selected 'Collation' named dropdown i made table name as "team" with number of fields as "3" then i modified fields like shown below

```
**Field            id                   url                        shortened**
Type             INT                 VARCHAR                     VARCHAR

Lenght/Values    255                 10000                       10000  
Default          None                None                        None
```

Then i made 'id' as Primary Key

These are some part of php code where database handling going one
in sortner.php

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("leaf", $con); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name
$urlinput=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url']); 
$id=rand(10000,99999);
$shorturl=base_convert($id,20,36);
$sql = "insert into team values('$id','$urlinput','$shorturl')";
mysql_query($sql,$con);
echo "Shortened url is <a href=\"http://projects.devlup.com/url/". $shorturl ."\">http://devlup.com/". $shorturl ."</a>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

In decoder.php

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("leaf", $con); //Replace with your MySQL DB Name


$de= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["decode"]);



$sql = 'select * from team where shortened="$de"';

$result=mysql_query("select * from team where shortened='$de'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$res=$row['url'];
header("location:$res");
}
```

Kindly let me know anything is wrong here,,My all files are under root folder(www) that means C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\test

Comment: Is this a homework assignment somewhere? [URL shortner issue in php](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6162956)

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you have the rewrite rule added?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
#
# Internally rewrite shortened URL requests to de-shortened URL lookup script filepath plus query string
RewriteRule ^([\w\d]{4})$ decoder.php?decode=$1 [L]
```

check that. otherwise check just doing

```
http://yourdomain.com/decoder.php?decode=<URL>
```

and check if you see anything there.

also: an ugly but fast way to debug is add `die('somehing');` and keep moving it trough the script to see where the script stops

### EDIT 2:

your script could be simple as this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM team WHERE shortened = '$de' LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$res = $row['url'];
header("Location: $res");
exit;
```

Also, from your comments, where is your script? is it under the folder `url` or in the root folder? that could make work or not the rewrite rule

### EDIT 1:

Also:

- add to the end of the query `LIMIT 1` (since you would only have 1 url for the short string)
- you don't need to keep iteration, just call `mysql_fetch_array` once
- change `location` for `Location` and add `exit` after that sentence

Comment: i didnt get the one which you mentioned changing the location

Comment: can you clear the statement which you mentioned about LIMIT 1 and about the iteration about mysql_fetch_array

Comment: I modidifed the Rewrite rule in .htacces file by giving appropriate line breaking and spaces Still getting blank page with url as http://projects.devlup.com/url/(alphanumeric characters)

Comment: My all files are under root folder(www) that means C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.6.0\www\test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your problem detail is already detailed, but if you think it is a problem with getting the shortened URL from the database, then at least trying to debug your code and see what's happening around, something like:

```
$de= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["decode"]);

echo "Shortened code: $de \n";

$result = mysql_query("select * from team where shortened='$de'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    var_dump($result);
    $res=$row['url'];
    echo "Raw URL: $res \n";
    //header("location:$res");
}
```

I also developed an URL shortener script myself, distributed [here](http://www.binpress.com/app/urlite--your-own-short-urls/375). I know quite a lot about how to make it so probably I can help you if you provide enough information. You can try my demo at: http://trisle.net/u/

Hope I can help.